# How does ray deal with variables of enclosing scope?

Tags: ray

Consider the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import ray
import time

A = np.array([42] * 4200)   

@ray.remote
def foo1(x):
    x[5]**2

@ray.remote
def foo2(j):
    A[j]**2

ray.init()

#
# some warmup for ray
#

start = time.perf_counter()
for _ in range(1000):
    ray.get(foo1.remote(A))
time_foo1 = time.perf_counter() - start

start = time.perf_counter()
for _ in range(1000):
    ray.get(foo2.remote(5))
time_foo2 = time.perf_counter() - start

print(time_foo1, time_foo2)

ray.shutdown()
```

It appears that `time_foo2` is significantly smaller than `time_foo1`. My naive guess would be that ray is serializing `A` each time `foo1` is called. However, even if I manually put `A` in the object storage and pass the object reference to `foo1`, I don't see any improvement. Could somebody enlighten me what is going on here behind the scenes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run your code I get `0.8745803280000004 0.672677727`. So foo2 is smaller, but not by much (perhaps `A` was larger in your original code?). That being said, here's an explanation of what ray is doing.

When a function is annotated with `ray.remote` it is serialized so that it can be sent to remote processes to run. Ray uses [cloudpickle](https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle) for serialization. When a function is serialized, its global dependencies are also serialized.

In the following example, `A` is an example of a dependency on a global variable that must be serialized.

```
@ray.remote
def foo2(j):
    A[j]**2
```

When a remote function is called, Ray must pass the arguments to the remote function. There are optimizations for small objects, but for large objects the logic roughly follows:

```
for each arg:
    if arg is an ObjectRef,
        do nothing
    else,
        replace arg with ray.put(arg)
```

On the remote worker, when the remote function is invoked, we call `ray.get` on all ObjectRefs before actually invoking the function (again, we're only focusing on large objects). `ray.get` can benefit from optimizations like caching or zero-copy reads so it's often times much cheaper than `ray.put`.

In practice this means that the following code

```
@ray.remote
def foo(arg):
    # At this point ray.get(arg_ref) has already happened

A = np.arange(1_000_000)
foo.remote(A) # This is the same as foo.remote(ray.put(A))
foo.remote(A) # Same as foo.remote(ray.put(A)), which means it has happened twice now
```

Whereas if we explicitly call `ray.put` we can save ourselves a `put`

```
A_ref = np.put(A) 
foo.remote(A_ref) # ray.put is not called here
foo.remote(A_ref) # again, ray.put is not called
```

When I run these examples with a 1 million entry matrix for `A` I get the following times ([here's my sample code](https://gist.github.com/wuisawesome/c4b99b740bd78bc87e1329a631077d2c)):

```
Time putting A every time: 3.041259899
Time passing ref of A: 0.7547513060000002
Time serializing A in function: 0.7694220469999999
```

Note that while serializing A was fast, it is a bad practice and not recommended. This is because objects are put in the object store, and serialized functions are put in the control store, and the control store is not built for passing around large amounts of data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comprehensive answer!